# Show that set $\{x\in]0,1[:f(x)=\alpha\}$, $\forall \alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ is measurable but $f$ is not.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This is a exercise of my course in Measure and Integration. I did one part but the end is confounding me and I don't know do.

**The exercise**

> We view in class that if $E$ is a measurable set in $\mathbb{R}$ (denote $\mathscr{M}_L(\mathbb{R})$) and $f\rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is a measurable function, so $$\{x\in E: f(x)=\alpha\}\in\mathscr{M}_L(\mathbb{R}), \forall \alpha \in \overline{\mathbb{R}}$$
>
> Show that exists a subset $A\subset]0,1[$ that is not measurable. Consider the function $f:]0,1[\rightarrow\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ such that:
>   $$
> f(x)=
> \left\{
> \begin{array}{ll}
> x  &\textrm{ if } x\in A \\
> -x &\textrm{ if } x\not\in A 
> \end{array}
> \right.
> $$
>   Show that $\{x\in]0,1[:f(x)=\alpha\}$ is measurable for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is not a function measurable.

**What I do**

I get the Vitali set ( see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set ) and called $A=V$. Ok, this struck me well. But the in the last part I give that:

$\alpha\in V\Rightarrow \{x\in E: f(x)=\alpha\}=V\not\in\mathscr{M}_L(\mathbb{R})$ and that this confusing me. I do not know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, by definition, $f$ is injective, so we have that
$$
\{x\in (0,1)\mid f(x)=\alpha\}=\{\alpha\}
$$
Or 
$$
\{x\in (0,1)\mid f(x)=\alpha\}=\{-\alpha\}
$$
If we denote by $\chi_A$ the characteristic function of $A$, we can simplify this by setting
$$
\{x\in (0,1)\mid f(x)=\alpha\}=\{(-1)^{\chi_A(\alpha)+1}\alpha\}
$$
Whichever is the case, the set $\{x\in (0,1)\mid f(x)=\alpha\}$ is a singleton and it is well known that all singletons are measurable. Therefore, for all $\alpha\in (0,1)$, the set $\{x\in (0,1)\mid f(x)=\alpha\}$ is measurable.

To show that $f$ is not measurable, you can take a look to the set
$$
\{x\in (0,1)\mid f(x)>0\}=f^{-1}((0,\infty))
$$
Is this set measurable? If $f$ were measurable, it should be (by definition)

Comment: Following you I will get it: $\{x\in]0,1[:f(x)>0 \}=f^{-1}((0,\infty))=V \not\in\mathscr{M}_L$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.